# Adding a second to time for every cell in an excel file, store each time in an array

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have an initial timestamp and an excel file I load using pandas. How do I increment this time by 1 second for each row of the excel file?

I have tried a for loop and `timedelta` but I'm getting a `'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` error

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time


timestamp1=1563855441
s_datetime=time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", time.localtime(timestamp1))
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(s_datetime, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')

time=[]

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    newTime=datetime_object+timedelta(seconds=i)
    time.append[newTime]
```

ideally, the array would look something like this

```
time=[2019-07-22 23:17:21, 2019-07-22 23:17:22, 2019-07-22 23:17:23, ... ]
```

My problem also has to do with accounting for changes to the days at most (the file probably won't be large enough to change more than 2 days)

Comment: your code, as written is appending the same time to the list over and over again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple fix.

`time.append()` is a function. You are calling it as `time.append[]` with the `[]` operator which is attempting to do a `__getitem__` on the function object itself.

Replace `time.append[newTime]` with `time.append(newTime)`